What is the need of induction in proving uniqueness of cardinality of sets?
In Analysis 1 by Terence Tao and here and basically every proof I read, I find that the proof is done by induction.
But in the attached link the proof starts by stating that:
$\mid A\mid =n$  and $\mid A\mid =m$ implies the existence of the bijections $f:\mathbb{N_n}\rightarrow A$ and $g:\mathbb{N_m}\rightarrow A$. But since $g$ is bijective and hence invertible then $g^{-1}:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N_m}$ is also a bijection.
That implies that the composition $g^{-1}\circ f:\mathbb{N_n}\rightarrow \mathbb{N_m}$ is also a bijection.
After that the proof continues by induction.
What I'm asking is since there exists a bijection from $\mathbb{N_n}$ to $\mathbb{N_m}$ and hence by definition they have equal cardinality isn't that enough as a proof of unique cardinality? Why do we need induction?

The freedom to choose the bijections requires us to ensure they all give the same cardinality. Naively you're ensuring that changing the order you count the elements in doesn't change how many there are.

@CyclotomicField Could you please elaborate? I didn't understand your comment.

What is being proved is that if there exists bijections $f:\mathbb{N}_n\rightarrow A$ and $g:\mathbb{N}_m\rightarrow A$ then $n=m$. Induction is still needed to prove that $n=m$.

Yes, a common definition of cardinalities is as equivalence classes of sets under equipotence/bijection/isomorphism. Then the cardinality of a set is unique by definition.
What the linked proof is showing is that finite cardinalities represented as natural numbers are unique, in the sense that $\mathbb{N}_n \cong \mathbb{N}_m$ implies $n = m$. This requires induction.

I think I understand now. Induction is needed to prove that a bijection from ${1,2,3,....,n}$ and ${1,2,3,....,m}$ exists if and only if $n=m$. If this is right, then I got the answer I was looking for.
